# what does the function! mean in vimscript?

Tags: vim

what does the function! mean in vimscript,

I learned vimscript from:
http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/38.html

what different between `function` and `function!` ?

Answer (score 2):

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html

> To redefine a function that already exists, use the ! for the
>   ":function" command:
>
> :function!  Min(num1, num2, num3)